# Webpack build error for bootstrap

Tags: node.js, web, npm, webpack, bootstrap-4

When I proceeded to build, the following "Warning" occurs.
How do I fix this?

And is there no command to build in real time, other than "$ npm run build"?
ex) $ sass --watch

Or live preview

```
  $ npm run build

    > bootstrap-webpack@1.0.0 build /Users/suk/myweb
    > webpack

    Hash: 62314a5e1bd8f234994f
    Version: webpack 4.16.1
    Time: 7100ms
    Built at: 2018-07-18 19:27:20
        Asset     Size  Chunks                    Chunk Names
    bundle.js  328 KiB       0  [emitted]  [big]  main
    [0] ./src/app.js 45 bytes {0} [built]
    [4] (webpack)/buildin/global.js 489 bytes {0} [built]
    [5] ./src/scss/app.scss 1.35 KiB {0} [built]
    [6] ./node_modules/css-loader!./node_modules/postcss-loader/lib??ref--4-2!./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js!./src/scss/app.scss 165 KiB {0} [built]
        + 6 hidden modules

    WARNING in configuration
    The 'mode' option has not been set, webpack will fallback to 'production' for this value. Set 'mode' option to 'development' or 'production' to enable defaults for each environment.
    You can also set it to 'none' to disable any default behavior. Learn more: https://webpack.js.org/concepts/mode/

    WARNING in asset size limit: The following asset(s) exceed the recommended size limit (244 KiB).
    This can impact web performance.
    Assets: 
      bundle.js (328 KiB)

    WARNING in entrypoint size limit: The following entrypoint(s) combined asset size exceeds the recommended limit (244 KiB). This can impact web performance.
    Entrypoints:
      main (328 KiB)
          bundle.js


    WARNING in webpack performance recommendations: 
    You can limit the size of your bundles by using import() or require.ensure to lazy load some parts of your application.
    For more info visit https://webpack.js.org/guides/code-splitting/
```

Comment: Note please(for --watch) : https://webpack.js.org/guides/development/.                 You can instruct webpack to "watch" all files within your dependency graph for changes. If one of these files is updated, the code will be recompiled so you don't have to run the full build manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
WARNING in configuration
    The 'mode' option has not been set, webpack will fallback to 'production' for this value. Set 'mode' option to 'development' or 'production' to enable defaults for each environment.
    You can also set it to 'none' to disable any default behavior. Learn more: https://webpack.js.org/concepts/mode/
```

This error can be fixed by adding a --mode production(or devevelopment) depending on which env you are targetting. Or, you can also put on your webpack config:

```
{
  mode: "development"
  ...
}
```

The other ones are just hints, for you to make your application better, you can ignore them if you want, or you can disable that by adding this to your webpack config:

```
performance: {hints: false}
```

To add that to the command line, edit your package.json and add this alogside with webpack:

`webpack --mode development`.

To have webpack watching for changes:

`webpack --mode development --watch`

Comment: What exactly different between "development" and "production"?

Comment: ex ) sass compile command line is " $ sass --watch style.scss:style.css

Comment: Do not have --watch function in npm?

Comment: there are some optimizations out of the box for those different envieronments, you just add them depending on your target.

Comment: Your output "-bash: webpack: command not found" in provided command.
What do problem?

provided command :
$ webpack --mode development
$ webpack --mode development --watch

my cd :
webpack installed folder

Comment: You create an  npm script for that. The same way that the build was created.

Comment: do input "$ npm webpack --mode development"?

Comment: You have to edit your package.json and add that to your scripts, on the scripts property.

Comment: "module.exports = {
  mode: "development","         |    it's right?

Comment: This is getting beyond the scope of your initial question, this can polute in case others have the same problem

Comment: I suggest you looking into npm scripts and how to get started with webpack.